# angular use logix and request in index.html

Tags: html, angular

In index.html i have loading screen with img

```
    <div class="loading-screen" style="...">
        <img src="/assets/image/logo.png">
    </div>
```

in app.component.ts after loading some files i do:

```
  const screen = document.querySelector('.loading-screen');
  screen['style'].opacity = 0;
```

to hide it.

Now I want this screen to show the image received from the server backend. That is, I request a picture on the server with a get request, if it exists, uses it, if not, leaving the same default one. I don't understand how to do it because all other components and services are initialized after index.html. How can I implement this kind of logic?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking basically how to make the image show up on a separate html page?

Comment: no, i am asking how to make a get request and use the received data in index.html